# Define Self as multiple attributes in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm new to Django and building my first app.

I want locations in my Admin section to be displayed by a combination of different attributes from the model.

Currently they are shown by the icon by using the following code.

```
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.icon
```

I want to be able to add my other two attributes to this code so that the result will look like.

"Icon(Attribute1, Attribute2)"

How can I edit the code to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly then the following should produce the result that you are looking for (but you'll need to edit the attribute names):

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u"{0} ({1}, {2})".format(self.icon, self.attrib1, self.attrib2)
```